# jQuery returns wrong HTML

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, hogan.js

**Problem**: jQuery returns wrong HTML value 
**jQuery version**: jquery-1.10.2.min.js

For some reason `$("#peopleTemplate").html()` returns wrong HTML.
Instead of returning,

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#people}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{FirstName}}</td>
            <td>{{LastName}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/people}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

, jQuery returns the following.

```
        {{#people}}

        {{/people}}
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr>
            <td>{{FirstName}}</td>
            <td>{{LastName}}</td>

        </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

What is it that I am missing?

Here is the full source in question.

```
@using Demo.Javascript.Template.Hogan.Models
@model List<Person>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "People";
}

<h2>People</h2>

<div id="peopleTemplate" class="template">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#people}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{FirstName}}</td>
                <td>{{LastName}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/people}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="main"></div>

<script language="javascript">
    debugger;
    //var data = { "people" : @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model)) };
    var data = {
        "people": [
            { "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Doe" },
            { "FirstName": "Jane", "LastName": "Doe" },
            { "FirstName": "Robert", "LastName": "Smith" },
            { "FirstName": "Mike", "LastName": "Durden" },
            { "FirstName": "Marilin", "LastName": "Monroe" }
        ]
    };
    var template = Hogan.compile($("#peopleTemplate").html());
    var rendered = template.render(data);
    $("#main").html(rendered);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template HTML is invalid, try wrapping your template with the a `<script>` tag like the following:

```
<script id="peopleTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div class="template">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{#people}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{FirstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{LastName}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{/people}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</script>
```

Working version: http://jsfiddle.net/fcbwh1wp/

Comment: For some reason, visual studio is complaining that HTML element within script is not right and thus formatting the code incorrectly... as you can see here http://imgur.com/e5qsLGk . But I am double/triple checking if I did anything wrong.

Comment: @Sung try setting `type="text/html"` on the `script` tag and move the `class` attribute to the `div` block.

Comment: Adding `type="text/html"` fixed the issue. This looks like a more elegant solution than commenting out hogan/mustache tags. Thanks, Brent.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the return you are expecting should not be known because your HTML is completely invalid.  You cannot have text in a `<tbody>` element.

> {{#people}}
>
> You have used character data somewhere it is not permitted to appear. Mistakes that can cause this error include:
>
> - putting text directly in the body of the document without wrapping it in a container element (such as a `<p>`Paragraph`</p>`), or
> - forgetting to quote an attribute value (where characters such as "%" and "/" are common, but cannot appear without surrounding quotes),
> - or
>     using XHTML-style self-closing tags (such as ) in HTML 4.01 or earlier. To fix, remove the extra slash ('/') character. For more information about the reasons for this, see Empty elements in SGML, HTML, XML, and XHTML.

Comment: I got the idea from the answer that I cannot have invalid element within `<tbody>` element. So what I did was to comment them out just like shown here. http://i.imgur.com/TmAsTlf.png . It's a bit cumbersome but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with non-valid HTML.

The only direct child elements that a `<tbody>` tag is allow to have are `<tr>` elements.  `{{#people}}` is not a `<tr>` tag, and therefore not a valid child.  Please reference the [W3 definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tbody.html) for the `<tbody>` tag.

I would assume that your browser is correcting the HTML when the page is rendered, and jQuery is returning exactly what is represented in your DOM structure (which is different than viewing the source).  This is a common feature of browsers to correct HTML for missing tags, or other common mistakes to attempt to correct the HTML structure.

Comment: thanks for the answer but when I sorted the answer by time, Erik's answer showed up first. But thank you for your answer so 1+